# sctp multihoming with zero window probing

Tags: sctp, multihomed

I have query, regarding zero window probing in multihoming. when zero window probing occurs RFC 4960(sec 6.1A) zero says one data chunk should be in flight per destination transport address

But if i have multihoming application with two source and two destination ip address. should there be two data chinks in flight per address or a single data chunk should be in flight ?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have multiple multihomed addresses on your destination, only one data chunk will be in flight. Multihomed addresses are used for failover (so if sending to one address fails, SCTP will retransmit to a different address).